# How to run multiple instances of the same Python script which uses subprocess.call

Tags: python, bash, terminal, subprocess, background-process

I have a Python script `job.py` which accepts command-line arguments. The script uses the Python package `subprocess` to run some external programs. Both the script and the external programs are sequential (i.e. no MPI, openMP, etc.). I want to run this script 4 times, each time with different command-line arguments. My processor has 4 cores and therefore I would like to run all 4 instances simultaneously. If I open 4 terminals and run each instance of the script in the separate terminals it works perfectly and I get exactly what I want.

Now I want to make it easier for myself to launch the 4 instances such that I can do all of this with a single command from a single terminal. For this I use a bash script `batch.sh`:

```
python job.py 4 0 &
python job.py 4 1 &
python job.py 4 2 &
python job.py 4 3 &
```

This does not work. It turns out that `subprocess` is the culprit here. All the Python code runs perfectly until it hits `subprocess.call` after which I get:

```
[1]+  Stopped                 python job.py 4 0
```

So how I see it, is that I am trying to run `job.py` in the background and `job.py` itself tries to run something else in the background via `subprocess`. This apparently does not work for reasons I do not understand.

Is there a way to run `job.py` multiple times without requiring multiple terminals?

**EDIT #1**

On recommendation I tried the `multiprocessing`, `thread` and `threading` packages. In the best case just one instance ran properly. I tried an ugly workaround which does work. I made a bash script which launches each instance in a new terminal:

```
konsole -e python job.py 4 0
konsole -e python job.py 4 1
konsole -e python job.py 4 2
konsole -e python job.py 4 3
```

**EDIT #2**

Here is the actual function that uses `subprocess.call` (note: `subprocess` is imported as `sp`).

```
def run_case(path):
    case = path['case']
    os.chdir(case)
    cmd = '{foam}; {solver} >log.{solver} 2>&1'.format(foam=CONFIG['FOAM'],
                                                       solver=CONFIG['SOLVER'])
    sp.call(['/bin/bash', '-i', '-c', cmd])
```

Let me fill in the blank spots:

- `CONFIG` is a globally defined dictionary.
- `CONFIG['FOAM'] = 'of40'` and this is an alias in my .bashrc used to source a file belonging to the binary I'm running.
- `CONFIG['SOLVER'] = 'simpleFoam'` and this is the binary I'm running.

**EDIT #3**

I finally got it to work with this

```
def run_case():
    case = CONFIG['PATH']['case']
    os.chdir(case)
    cmd = 'source {foam}; {solver} >log.simpleFoam 2>&1'.format(foam=CONFIG['FOAM'],
                                                                solver=CONFIG['SOLVER'])
    sp.call([cmd], shell=True, executable='/bin/bash')
```

The solution was to set both `shell=True` and `executable='/bin/bash'` instead of including `/bin/bash` in the actual command-line to pass to the shell. NOTE: `foam` is now a path to a file instead of an alias.

Comment: `Stopped` may just mean that the instance of `job.py` finished.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the `subprocess` module.  I think the program you are running wants to write to `stdout`, and receives a `SIGTTOU` because you've placed it in the background so it doesn't have access to your controlling terminal.  This is standard behavior.  Capturing the output from the program (setting `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` and `stderr=subprocess.PIPE`) might work, although then you will need to handle program output correctly (see `subprocess.Popen` and the `communicate` method).

Comment: you should use threading to access your different cores. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

Comment: `sp.call([cmd], shell=True)` is wrong, it coincidentally works but you really mean `sp.call(cmd, shell=True)` without the `[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parallelize from within Python:

```
import multiprocessing
import subprocess

def run_job(spec):
    ...
    if spec ...:
        subprocess.call(...)

def run_all_jobs(specs):
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
    pool.map(run_job, specs)
```

It has the advantage of letting you monitor/log/debug the parallelization.

Comment: I tried this, but it will only run one of the jobs. To run the others in the pool I have to type `fg` in the terminal. Somehow `subprocess.call` is having a locking behaviour, because everything before `subprocess.call` runs as expected. If I comment out every `subprocess.call` then all jobs run until completion (naturally without doing anything useful).

Comment: What are you calling with `subprocess.call()`? Are you using `shell=True`?

Comment: I tried it both with `shell` set to `True` and `False`. See **EDIT #2** in OP to see the function that uses `subprocess.call`.

Comment: You are calling `bash` from the `call()`. You can instead use separate `call()`  statements over the programs of interest, capture the output in Python, and write to the log file from within Python.

Comment: I finally got it to work. See OP for the solution. Thanks for all the help!